# Create QR code in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6, qr-code

I have seen some example codes, these code are creating QR codes froms Text (below is the code).can we generate QR codes from other data also (like Image)?

```
 NSString *code = @"1001012023034";

Barcode *barcode = [[Barcode alloc] init];

self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

[barcode setupQRCode:code];
self.imageView.image = barcode.qRBarcode;
```

My question is if we use Image instead of string data then is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QR codes are pretty limited in terms of data storage, limited to a few kb - see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_code#Storage for storage sizes. As such, you won't be able to put an image in there. What you CAN do, however, is upload the image somewhere and encode a link to that image instead.

Answer (score 3):

**Yes**, It's Possible. There are two Best Libraries available :

**1)** For **Encoding :** [QR-Code-Encoder-for-Objective-C](https://github.com/myang-git/QR-Code-Encoder-for-Objective-C)

**2)** For **Decoding :** [ZBar bar code reader](http://zbar.sourceforge.net/iphone/)

GoodLuck.