# QR code reader for iPhone. Z-Xing is too big

Tags: iphone, qr-code

Is there a current iPhone QR library? Zebra Xing is pretty huge for the small app that I plan to make. ZBar has the wrong kind of license. Any suggestions would be well appreciated. All it has to do is recognize a QR code and interpret it, hopefully at a high frame rate. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check My Answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/16056559/1603072

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also try shop savvy iphone sdk for read qr code : http://shopsavvy.mobi/sdk/

Zbar is the best. Easy to integrate and good documentation is there. See their site http://zbar.sourceforge.net/. And see their tutorial http://zbar.sourceforge.net/iphone/sdkdoc/tutorial.html.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can do using this :

ZBar = [SDK](http://sourceforge.net/projects/zbar/files/iPhoneSDK/beta/)

and
 use this step which gives by this answer 
 [Zbar SDK is not working in iOS6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12506671/zbar-sdk-is-not-working-in-ios6)

other source =
 [See this Link](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=Qr)

Answer (score 0):

This one looks good, we are using it: [Esponce QR Reader](http://itunes.apple.com/app/id544799277) - it is fast, nice looking, easy to use and it recognize all fields from contact cards correctly, also unicode chars.