# What is the best QR code reader to implement in iOs?

Tags: ios, qr-code

I want to implement a QR code reader in my iPhone application .

I have used the Zxing APIs once, but i think it's too much for a simple thing. Can I use any other library for the same purpose?

thanks!

Comment: Check My Answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/16056559/1603072

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this [ZBar:](http://zbar.sourceforge.net/iphone/sdkdoc/install.html)

and you can get tutorial from [here.](http://zbar.sourceforge.net/iphone/sdkdoc/tutorial.html)

If you want  example project I took from [here.](https://github.com/arciem/ZBarSDK)

try it out, it is simple one.

Answer (score 4):

ZBar SDK ...easy to use and open source

https://github.com/arciem/ZBarSDK

Comment: I would completely agree with this, it is simple to use, reads classic barcodes as well as QR codes. Importantly it is also free. I looked into RedLaser when I was doing it as well and it is really good but it has a huge price tag associated with it.